# Google hangout button on iphone

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

The new google hangout button enables to embed hangouts on websites, but it is not supported by iphone .

Google + iphone app enables hangouts with iphone devices.

Is there a way to use a hangout on iphone with the hangout button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time you cannot launch hangouts on mobile devices using the hangout button.

Mobile devices can only use hangouts from the native mobile applications.

Comment: What about Android intents? Is there an intent for launching hangouts?

Comment: An authoritative link would be great (:

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could load it via a UIWebView loaded on a users's page or just loaded on a specific page design of yours including your hangout button?

Comment: The problem isn't the button but the hungout itself - I think that iphone's safari client doesn't support google hangouts.

Comment: Yeah you might be right. It seems that there's a lot of tech behind google hangouts, and even though they say it's kinda cloud apped, it wouldn't be surprising that it's not supported yet by Safari ( or that Google Hangout hasn't been added with a compatibility layer for it ). I'm having some reads here and there to get more insights on the matter. Interesting subject.